# DWT or WP for signal filtration

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, frequency-analysis, wavelet

I'm dealing with a tricky problem related to the wavelet transform (tricky at least for me :). I have a signal, say a sinusoid (frequency f1) with another sinusoid (freq. f2) superposed. If the other signal has higher frequency than the original one, no problem with its filtration appears. However, this is not my case as I have to deal with two signals with similar frequencies, for example, f2 = 1.2 f1. Is there any way to reconstruct the original sinusoid using wavelet transformation, preferably DWT or wavelet packages? I would probably better benefit from CWT as it shows complete time-scale properties, but it is not the option.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a frequency versus time uncertainty issue.  You will need longer basis vectors to separate spectral content that is closer together in frequency.

For a delta F of 0.2, you might want to try using basis vectors that are in the range of 10 times longer than the period(s) of the sinusoids of interest.

Comment: Yes I know, but how to achieve this with DWT/WP? The time-frequency issue is closely related to the continuous wavelet transform, but my point is to avoid it and to use the discrete variants instead.